# SQL(Snowflake) - Removing duplicates from number extraction

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to extract these numbers from a string but only keep unique numbers. There are strings that contain more than 3 unique numbers in them as well.

How do I extract all numbers from a string while removing duplicates? (Most digits will be 7-8 characters in length)

```
     SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(string,' '),'[[:digit:]]{8}',1,1)||' '||REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(string,' '),'[[:digit:]]{8}',1,1)||' '||REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(string,' '),'[[:digit:]]{8}',1,1) as Num_Value 
FROM ( *select DESCRIPTION as string
      from...*)
    ) 
WHERE Num_Value IS NOT NULL
```

---

**Strings**

1. "Contract No(s). 02241899, 02749981, (as..."
2. "Contract No(s). 02515351,02747764,02707694 (as..."
3. "Contract No(s). 02667112, (as..."

**My Results**

1. 02241899 02241899 02241899
2. 02515351 02515351 02515351
3. 02667112 02667112 02667112

**What I'm Looking For**

1. 02241899 02749981
2. 02515351 02747764 02707694
3. 02667112

Comment: Are the numbers always between `No(s).` and `(as...` ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but majority would be like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to just not use the `regex` and instead split to table based on a reliable delimiter

```
with t1 (id, str) as
(select 1, 'Contract No(s). 02241899, 02749981, (as...') 
          
select distinct 
       t1.id, 
       t1.str,
       t2.value as contact
from t1,lateral split_to_table(replace(t1.str,' ',','), ',') t2
where try_cast(t2.value as integer) is not null and
      len(t2.value) in (7,8);
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but it's combining the numbers from 3 separate rows into 1 row. I basically need this but it needs to be applied to each row separately so I can have a column to the right of the description with the extracted numbers. The result I get from this answer is 1 column 1 row 02241899 02749981 02515351 02667112 02747764 02707694

Comment: @ninja You mean have extracted numbers on separate rows per description instead of concatenated?

Comment: exactly! No concatenation

Comment: Amazing! This does it! Thank you